# Clojure: multiple type hints?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

How to specify the possibility of two types to a variable?

```
(defn connect! [(or ^:String :^java.net.InetAddress) host ^:Integer port] ...)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The purpose of type-hinting is to allow the compiler to avoid reflection. Allowing a form to be type-hinted as two different classes would defeat that purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Clojure documentation](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints):

> Clojure supports the use of type hints to assist the compiler in avoiding reflection in performance-critical areas of code. Normally, one should avoid the use of type hints until there is a known performance bottleneck

The purpose of type hints is to allow the compiler to avoid reflection. Any self-documentation aspects of type-hinted code are secondary. When you say the following:

```
(defn connect! [^String host])
```

What you're telling the compiler is to resolve all Java interop method calls on `host` at compile time to method calls on the `String` class. Allowing a form to be hinted with multiple classes would defeat this purpose - the compiler wouldn't know which class to compile a method call as. Even if it did, an object cannot be a `String` and an `InetAddress` at the same time, so any method calls compiled against the `String` class would be guaranteed to fail with a `ClassCastException` if an `InetAddress` happened to be passed in, and vice versa.

Comment: I had in mind self documentation, but yeah, I suppose that can be achieve with a doc string. thanks.

Comment: @leontalbot If you haven't already, take a look at [Prismatic schema](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema) for self-documenting function definitions with support for unions and runtime validation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the only way is to do the check yourself and add the hint inside a let:

```
(condp instance? host
  String (let [^String s] (...))
  InetAddress (let [^InetAddress a] (...)))
```

Comment: This will work, but I would treat this as a sort of code smell - it's begging to be refactored using a protocol or multimethod.